# What's the proper way of using Capybara in Rails 3.x functional tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

So Rails generates some functional tests for controllers in the `test/functional` directory. These tests are extending from `ActionController::TestCase`.

But in Capybara's web site, they only show how to prepare the integration tests by monkey patching `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::DSL

  # Stop ActiveRecord from wrapping tests in transactions
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  teardown do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean # Truncate the database
    Capybara.reset_sessions! # Forget the (simulated) browser state
    Capybara.use_default_driver # Revert Capybara.current_driver to Capybara.default_driver
  end
end
```

But they don't mention how to setup Capybara to be used with functional tests. What's the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't use Capybara, because that is a tool for Web pages. Functional testing does not involve that. You just have to prove that your controller logic has the right behaviour. For that RSpec is enough.

See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/frames *Controller Specs* section.

Answer (score 0):

Capybara provides some really nice syntax which can also be used in functional tests.  You just need to wrap the page function to return a Capybara::Node::Simple wrapped @response.body.

```
class Test::Unit::TestCase
  def page
    Capybara::Node::Simple.new(@response.body)
  end
end
```

From the Capybara rdoc:

A {Capybara::Node::Simple} is a simpler version of {Capybara::Node::Base} which includes only {Capybara::Node::Finders} and {Capybara::Node::Matchers} and does not include {Capybara::Node::Actions}.

Mo info:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/8087279685/use-capybara-on-any-html-fragment-or-page